# How to read a specific string from a file in c#?

Tags: c#

I am developing a project in which I need to read a specific name from a text file and match it with text-box value if it will match it shows a message otherwise some other working is performed.

[image]

It contains name if it matches with text-box value then it shows success message otherwise fail message.

Here is my code, in this code it read all the text, not a specific one.
if the string is found then it does not need to move towards next word to read.

my result is always no I don't know why?

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd =new OpenFileDialog(){ Filter = "Text Documents|*.txt", Multiselect=false, ValidateNames = true})
    {
        if(ofd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
            {
                if(textBox1.Text == await sr.ReadLineAsync())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ok");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("no");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the answer is always no, stands to reason the strings are different. Did you debug this? Step through it line by line? Check the values, including whitespace such as new line characters? Why are you using StreamReader instead of File.ReadAllText?

Comment: there is no new line in my case it will add text in only one line.

Comment: no strings are same always, you can say it copy paste and  no i did not debug it.

Answer (score 0):

try trimming both side or making them lower case,
like

```
if(textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() == await sr.ReadLineAsync().Trim().ToLower())
{
}
```

Comment: When I do my speech programs the same thing will happen, found out that both has to have same casing. For example,.. Tree and tree. Even though it's the same word one T is capital the other lowercase. Both has to be the same casing. Unless you call .ToLower();